# Como pegar informação de uma função e usar em outra?

Tags: c

Preciso de um programa que efetue soma e multiplicação conforme escolha do usuário e posteriormente selecione a função correspondente que irá ler os valores, até o usuário digitar 0 e o programa gerar o resultado. Meu programa para qualquer valor digitado está informando 36. E outra, se caso eu quisesse que repetir o processo (calcular), e dar a opção de sair, teria que usar um do `while`? mas quando vou sair do laço?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void soma(void){
 int valor, soma, result;
  soma = 0;
   printf("Foi escolhida a soma:\n\n");
    do{
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        soma= soma+valor;
        result=soma;
    }while(valor!=0);
      }

     void mult(void){
     int valor, mult,result;
     mult= 1;
     printf("Foi escolhida a multiplicacao:\n\n");
       do{
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        if(valor==0){
            break;
        }
        mult= mult*valor;
        result=mult;
    }while(valor!=0);
     }

      int main()
       {
        int op,result;

        printf("Informe a operacao desejada soma(1) ou produto (2):");
        scanf("%d", &op);


    if(op==1){
        soma();
    }
    else if(op==2){
        mult();
    }

        printf("O resultado foi: %d", result);
      return 0;
       }
```

Comment: O programa so faz duas operações multiplicação e soma?

Comment: Sim apenas isso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu código está pegando lixo. Você precisa passar os dados de uma função para outra. A variável `result` que existe dentro do `main()` não é a mesma variável dentro das outras funções. Em geral as variáveis são locais. Até existe variável global que poderia resolver isto, mas é o jeito errado de fazer em quase 100% das situações. Nem pense nisto.

Aproveitei para organizar o código, fica mais fácil identificar problemas e arrumei alguns outros pequenos problemas que podem pegar lixo também em outras situações, além de mudanças cosméticas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int soma(void) {
    int valor = 0, soma = 0;
    printf("Foi escolhida a soma:\n\n");
    do {
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        soma += valor;
    } while (valor != 0);
    return soma;
}

int mult(void) {
    int valor = 0, mult = 1;
    printf("Foi escolhida a multiplicacao:\n\n");
    do {
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        if (valor == 0) break;
        mult *= valor;
    } while (valor != 0);
    return mult;
}

int main() {
    int op = 0, result;
    printf("Informe a operacao desejada soma(1) ou produto (2):");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    if (op == 1) result = soma();
    else if (op == 2) result = mult();
    printf("O resultado foi: %d", result);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8X0fOc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tnzagboq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CallFunction.c).

Comment: Para repetir a pergunta e adicionar a possibilidade de sair 3, o que poderia fazer?

Comment: Para manter o padrão, eu escolheria o 0 para sair. Bastaria colocar um laço no `main()` como você fez dentro das outras funções. Se tiver dificuldade em fazer isto, abra outra pergunta com este assunto que nós respondemos para você.

Comment: Valeu! Agradeço pela ajuda! tem como "curtir"  ambas publicações?

Comment: Aqui não é rede social, então não pode curtir. Pode votar nas duas, como acho que já fez. E pode escolher apenas uma como a que foi mais útil para você.

Answer (score 2):

Como suas duas funções executam cálculo você deve especificar que ela retorna um determinado valor.

Veja a função `soma()`:

```
 int soma(void)
 {
    int valor, soma, result;
    soma = 0;
    printf("Foi escolhida a soma:\n\n");
    do
    {
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        soma= soma+valor;
    }
    while(valor!=0);

    return soma;
}
```

E a função **mult()**:

```
int mult(void)
{
    int valor, mult,result;
    mult= 1;
    printf("Foi escolhida a multiplicacao:\n\n");
    do{
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        if(valor==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        mult= mult*valor;
    }
    while(valor!=0);

    return mult;
}
```

Agora a implementação das funções:

```
int main()
{
    int op,result;

    printf("Informe a operacao desejada soma(1) ou produto (2):");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    if(op==1)
    {
        result = soma();
    }
    else if(op==2)
    {
        result = mult();
    }

    printf("O resultado foi: %d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Lembre-se sempre de definir o tipo de retorno de acordo com o dado que você esta trabalhando.